# How to replace only "stand alone" matches?

Tags: jquery, regex, svg

I have this code in javascript

```
var pts = "0 0, 0 1909, 2559 1909, 2559 0";
pts.replace(/0/g, '2');
```

The problem is that it replaces all zeros! And I want just the stand alone zeros to be replaced, how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
pts.replace(/\b0\b/g, '2');
```

There exists "\b" which marks a wordboundary!

Answer (score 6):

Just add word boundaries around the zero-

```
/\b0\b/g
```

Keep browsing around the [Regex Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) for any regex related queries.

Here's more reading on [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)